# Website spying my address using WebRTC - what can they see?

Tags: webrtc, ip-address, fingerprint, ipv4

Website I'm using connects from javascript to external WebRTC server to get information about me. They are getting response like this and sending selected information to their server.

```
RTCPeerConnectionIceEvent {isTrusted: true, candidate: RTCIceCandidate, type: 'icecandidate', target: RTCPeerConnection, currentTarget: RTCPeerConnection, …}
isTrusted: true
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
candidate: RTCIceCandidate
address: "[edd1:73ea:ef2e:73eb:f08b:73ec:4f62:4888]"
candidate: "candidate:842163049 1 udp 1677732095 edd1:73ea:ef2e:73eb:f08b:73ec:4f62:4888 52280 typ srflx raddr :: rport 0 generation 0 ufrag +UaO network-cost 999"
component: "rtp"
foundation: "842163049"
port: 52280
priority: 1677732095
protocol: "udp"
relatedAddress: "[::]"
relatedPort: 0
sdpMLineIndex: 0
sdpMid: "1"
tcpType: null
type: "srflx"
usernameFragment: "+UaO"
[[Prototype]]: RTCIceCandidate
composed: false
```

Can anybody point me to a documentation or explain what information is encoded in address: "[edd1:73ea:ef2e:73eb:f08b:73ec:4f62:4888]" and what they can find out about me? It looks like IPv6 address but it is not.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That section in the candidate line holds an IPv4 or IPv6 address. The address follows the priority `1677732095`. Here are a few resources with detailed documentation:

- https://webrtchacks.com/sdp-anatomy/
- https://www.slideshare.net/saghul/ice-4414037 (slide 14)
- https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-ice-rfc5245bis-14.html